# Multi Thread & Semaphore & Events

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, semaphore

I am trying to execute some commands that come from RabbitMQ. Its about 5 msgs/sec. So as are too many msg, I have to send to a thread to execute, but I dont have so many threads, so I put a limit of 10.

so the ideia was that the msgs would come to the worker, put in a queue and any of the 10 threads would peak and execute. All these using semaphore.

After some experiments, I don´t know why, but my thread only executes 3 or 4 items, after that it just stops with no error...

The problem I think is the logic when the event calls the method to execute, could not think in a better way...

Why just the first 4 msgs are processed??

What pattern or better way to do this?

Here are some parts of my code:

```
const int MaxThreads = 10;
private static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(MaxThreads, MaxThreads);
private static Queue<BasicDeliverEventArgs> queue = new Queue<BasicDeliverEventArgs>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
consumer.Received += (sender, ea) =>
               {
                var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mail>(ea.Body.GetString());
                Console.WriteLine($"Sub-> {m.Subject}");
                queue.Enqueue(ea);
                RUN();
              };

            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);

            Console.Read();
}

private static void RUN()
{
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                sem.WaitOne();
                var item = queue.Dequeue();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(sendmail, item);
            }
}

private static void sendmail(Object item)
{

//.....soem processing stuff....

//tell rabbitMq that everything was OK
channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: x.DeliveryTag, multiple: true);

//release thread
sem.Release();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could use a blocking collection here. It will simplify the code.
So your email sender would look something like that:

```
public class ParallelEmailSender : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> blockingCollection;

    public ParallelEmailSender(int threadsCount)
    {
        blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>());
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(SendInternal);
        }
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        blockingCollection.Add(message);
    }

    private void SendInternal()
    {
        foreach (string message in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // send method
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to add error catching logic and you could also improve the app shutting down process by using cancellation tokens.

I strongly suggest to read the great [e-book about multithreading programming](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) written by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: Thanks! but a dummy question... the message in SendInternal, is thread safe?

Comment: You will probably use some object that will represent the message, but only one thread will receive that. The sending code should be thread safe of course as it will be called from multiple threads.

Comment: Another point... should I instanteate the class ParallelEmailSender  inside the event that RabbitMQ sends? If so would be pointless, because when the event is trigger´d it sends just one message, so each message would instateate the class with XX threads inside and the ideia was to put each message inside a different thread/parallel collection..... am I correct?  take a look what I did https://gist.github.com/PtkFerraro/14385ec8426d5b0bfd9cdee84dd30989

Comment: You should have one instance of `ParallelEmailSender` and when you receive a message from RabbitMQ you just call `Send` method. Of course you will need to modify `ParallelEmailSender` a bit so it knows how to actually send emails.